# How do I add a new account for a SLURM user?

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to use `sacctmgr modify` to update user information, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the syntax should be:

```
# sacctmgr modify user name=USERNAME set acct+=GROUP
 Unknown option: acct+=GROUP
 Use keyword 'where' to modify condition
# sacctmgr modify user name=USERNAME set account+=GROUP
 Unknown option: account+=GROUP
 Use keyword 'where' to modify condition
```

(This is for Slurm version 17.11.3-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user+account combination is treated as an association in SLURM. To create a new association, just "create" a new user with the new account, for example:

`sacctmgr create user name=USERNAME account=GROUP`

Comment: Thinking of the user and account combination as an atomic unit makes perfect sense.

Comment: That line in my case shows account doesn't exist... contact your admin:/

Comment: @statsconchris it means you need to create the GROUP (aka. account)